# How can pass multiple parameters in NSURL string in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsurl

I am developing one app in that app I need pass more than one parameters at a time in NSURL
my code is

```
responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
ArrData = [NSMutableArray array];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=%@&to=%@&q=%@",strfrom,strto,strgo]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
//NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
//[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=%@&to=%@&q=1",strfrom,strto]];
```

the above code I need to pass more than one parameter Dynamically. is it possible ?
if it is, then how?
thanks & regards

Comment: try creating a separate string before adding to the URL  something like `NSSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=%@&to=%@&q=%@",strfrom,strto,strgo]` and then add this str to URL

Comment: First pass all parameters to NSString and then Assign Final string to NSURL.

Comment: I am not able to completely understand your question.You are still passing more than one parameter in your question

Comment: whats the problem now?

Comment: Try to use NSMutableString.

Comment: problem is solved.....thanks for all giveing different solutions for this problem

Comment: your problem is with NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try creating a separate string before adding to the URL something like

```
 NSSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=%@&to=%@&q=%@"‌​,strfrom,strto,strgo];
```

and then add this strURL to URL

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
```

finally add it to the request, your code is wrong where you adding url to request, URL is not a string it is a URL so it should be `requestWithURL` not `URLWithString`, it should be like this

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing many of these answers is missing is the use of `[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]` to avoid using invalid characters in the URL:

```
NSString *baseURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=%@&to=%@&q=%@",strfrom,strto,strgo];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[baseURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Comment: This is a good point but note that stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding does not fully URL encode your string.  it misses things such as / and &.  stackoverflow has a bunch of examples on how to make your own.

Comment: But trojanfoe's answer was, for me, an integral part of sending a unicode word as part of an URL. So +1 to him.